# how to access hidden button on a page?

Tags: java, web

I'm developing a program to navigate and perform actions on a page (scraper).

I'm using Java 8 + Jaunt API and I can fill forms of many pages around the web and submit this data.

I'm trying to access my profile in college page but the submit button is hidden and is generated by other code type.

I don't know how can I reach this button.

I'll let one example below:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: how about using javascript to do form.submit();

Comment: You could access it via a Greasemonkey script.

Comment: But... the API don't offer any tool or function to send javascript command.